# Применении метода toString на массивах

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Есть массив элементов. Применяю к нему метод `toString()`, как я понимаю теперь массив элементов должен быть представлен в виде строки `String`; почему не могу вывести строку?

Вот что выводится при выводе:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@5bf6b81c
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

В Джаве массивы тоже являются объектами. Поэтому вы получаете ту строку. Что бы получить текстовое представление массива, используйте

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...
    Arrays.toString(arrayHere);
```

Тогда к каждому объекту в массиве будет применен его метод toString, и вы получите более разборчивую строчку

Comment: Не все массивы являются объектами, скажем `int[]` не является объектом...

Comment: Barmaley, могли бы подробнее рассказать про int[]? А то я сегодня даже в книжки полез. У Эккеля сказано, что любой массив, это объект, в котором хранятся ссылки на объекты. Какого-то замечания по примитивам там не было. Если int[] не является объектом, то и методов length(), toString(), hashCode() и т.д. не было бы, по идее

Comment: > Не все массивы являются объектами, скажем int[] не является объектом...

+1, стоило бы использовать фразу "к каждому элементу в массива"

Comment: Ах! Да, согласен)

Answer (score 9):

Хотя метод toString и определен для всех элементов, но по умолчанию он выводит имя+hashcode. Если нужно, что бы выводило что то определенное - нужно переопределить этот метод и выводить то, что нужно. Если эти объекты написаны не Вами, то придется либо писать наследника с правильным методом, либо писать ручками вывод, это не так уж и сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить текстовое представление элементов массива, можно воспользоваться методом `Arrays.toString`, или можно свой метод придумать:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};

String str1 = Arrays.toString(arr);

String str2 = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .mapToObj(i -> "′" + i + "′")
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

System.out.println(str1); // [1, 2, 3]
System.out.println(str2); // ′1′, ′2′, ′3′
```