# Java: является ли объектом int[]?

Tags: java

По мотивам "[Нюанс при применении метода toString](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/223482/java-%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-tostring)"

@Barmaley:

> Не все массивы являются объектами,
>   скажем int[] не является объектом...

@Антон Феоктистов:

> Barmaley, могли бы подробнее
>   рассказать про int[]? А то я сегодня
>   даже в книжки полез. У Эккеля сказано,
>   что любой массив, это объект, в
>   котором хранятся ссылки на объекты.
>   Какого-то замечания по примитивам там
>   не было. Если int[] не является
>   объектом, то и методов length(),
>   toString(), hashCode() и т.д. не было
>   бы, по идее

Хотелось бы действително узнать по подробнее. Сам я этот язык ещё изучаю и интересны подобные нюансы.
**P.S.** Просьба не путать `int` с `int[]`. Переменная `int` как примитивный тип не может являться объектом. Вопрос именно о принадлежности массива `int` (`int[]`) к объектам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я ошибся. Переменные примитивных типов не являются объектами, а массивы примитивных типов уже объекты:

> An object is a class instance or an array.

Первоисточник [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)